# how to create reminder notification using webservices based on date

Tags: php, android, web-services, push-notification, notifications

I referred so many examples but I am not able to implement my concept, my theme is to get a notification when task date is today's date and regarding today's time schedule in my given web service. Like in my web service 'task_date' is      17-6-2016 and 'task_time' is 4:20pm when its comes notification appear 15 min ahead of the current time also appear on current time also.

here is my web service image:
[image]

Comment: use Google Cloud Messaging, the newest and recommended way is to use FCM, google provides all information including code to implement this service, which is widely used by the users to generate notifications now a days,
for more info refer https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: well.. it seems i have to learn FCM first

Comment: I was just like you finding for the solution, but believe this is the best service available which took only couple of day to learn, on both side android and services, i implemented this within 2 days.